# Unique key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table in mysql which has a many columns,one of them being time.I want HOUR(time) as unique key for the table,that is there should only be one record for every hour.How can i do it?

Comment: So the table should have maximum 24 rows?

Comment: For a  day,yes,but i have a different field for date,so it should be 24 rows for a day

Comment: I don't think this can easily be done in MySQL because you can't create an index on an expression. You need to add another column that contains the hour, create a unique index on that column and then create a trigger that updates the hour column when the time column is changed

Comment: You can use "generated column" in MySQL 5.7 or "virtual column" on MariaDB (with unique index).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple integer column as your hourly key constraint. The unique hour for each possible time can be determined by

```
select floor(now()/10000)
```

which will return something like

```
2015090511
```

for the current date 5.9.2015 at  11.25h

Comment: You could use `extract()`, couldn't you?

Comment: You could, but you would have to combine the components `year, month, day, hour` into an integer again after `extract`ing each one of them from `now()`.